# Using NerdCommenter to comment/uncomment blocks with old-style C comments

Tags: filetype-c, plugin-nerdcommenter

I'm using the NerdCommenters `leader c<space>` to toggle comments on blocks of C code, but when those blocks already contain C comments, they get replaced, by default with `[>` and `<]`, and toggling the comment back off doesn't replace these placeholder with `/*` and `*/` again.

I've learned doing  two explicit uncomments, or an explicit uncomment (`leader-cu`) after the uncommenting toggle, reverts the placeholders back to `/*` and `*/`.

Can things be set up so I don't need the extra uncomment?
I'd like to limit myself to using just `leader c<space>` (toggle comment).

Comment: You could open an issue in the main git repo of the plugin. The devs would know better.

Answer (score 0):

Still not solving your issue, but sort of a workaround:

Memorize to type `leader-cu.` to uncomment a comment with a nested one, the `.` repeats the last command.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but it doesn't work for me. I tried it and `.` is not repeating the `leader -cu`.

Comment: This might work if the plugin in question supports tpope's repeat.vim